# Using an old car as a generator

Tags: engine, electrical, transmission, diy, generator

This is a very general question asking for some specific answers. Essentially, I would like to take a vehicle and strip it down, and to turn it into a generator. I’d like to take advantage of the transmission to increase efficiency of the generator(go to appropriate gears depending on strain), as well as to use multiple alternators on a belt to provide adequate power for different areas of the home all from one motor. What all do I need to know to better ask this question or answer this question?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Consider also that a generator expects to operate at a steady rpm under load and no-load conditions. You may be able to use a gearbox to locate the correct rpm, but you would not be changing gears to establish a balance depending on load.

Comment: @fred_dot_u well what can I do to maximize efficiency depending on load automatically.

Comment: a conventional generator has reasonably tight rpm control. It would be necessary to have some form of feedback loop on the engine. When the rpm drops due to increased load, the feedback would increase throttle and vice versa. That's out of my league, however. A grass-roots approach might be to create this loop using cruise control, as they can be fairly responsive.

Comment: @fred_dot_u so would it be possible to put the speed sensor on the alternator to track the speed of the alternator, then by activating it at the optimal speed when it loses speed due to increased load it will compensate automatically?

Comment: You'd have to do some math to determine what point on the engine to put the "speedometer" sensor. They are frequently on the transmission and if your project contains the transmission, you are halfway there! The rest of the brains are in the car computer. You may be able to find an aftermarket cruise control kit to mate with the sensor, removing the car computer complexity.

Comment: From what model car did your engine originate? What model engine?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not motor vehicle maintenance it is really about Renewable energy and living space design.

Comment: Have you thought of the overall efficiency of the engine you are going to be using? What is the final outcome you desire? If it's to make things cheaper overall using a generator rather than pulling power from the grid, you're going to find it's way more expensive to build/run/maintain a generator than to just use what's available.

Comment: @fred_dot_u I am very familiar with onboard computers since my field is in computer programming/security/forensics, so the aftermarket kit may or may not be necessary, but good point about the speedometer sensor, since it’s calibrated for actual driving.

Comment: @fred_dot_u as far as what engine I am waiting to have all my facts together before I decide on an engine to get so that I don’t risk wasting money and time, but it will likely be a 2000-2003 year used from a local car lot.

Comment: @SolarMike good point, I will move to sustainability.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 thé goal overall is to have self sustainable power, water, and other amenities for emergency use.

Comment: Consider to search for aftermarket cruise control products that will help you match your selection.  You'll want a standard transmission to eliminate the energy losses of an automatic transmission torque converter. Watch out on the cruise control that they don't suggest to tie into the OBDII connector or the computer panel under the right side of the dash. I found this https://www.amazon.com/Rostra-250-1223-Universal-Electronic-Control/dp/B007ZCQD9S that includes a magnet sensor kit to give you full compatibility, regardless of engine chosen.

Comment: @fred_dot_u alrighty, very appreciated I will look into that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one point you should consider that you have not is to use the waste heat produced by the engine to provide hot water for the house.

The cooling radiator can be directed into the hot water tank easily, but to really improve the conversion efficiency you should arrange a heat exchanger to get the heat out of the exhaust gases as well.

For the generator, then you should match the design speed of the generator to the best power point of the engine ie when considering the best fuel consumption (known as BSFC brake specific fuel consumption) - this is not the same as max power...

If you size the generator appropriately then you can either do away with the alternator and charge the battery from the main generator or keep it, but you should not need to use multiple alternators as the losses reduce the total efficiency.

For more information look at CHP (Combined Heat and Power) and Micro CHP
Some links are :
http://www.greenspec.co.uk/building-design/micro-chp/
http://www.cogeneurope.eu/medialibrary/2015/05/19/d6648069/miro-CHP%20study_merged.pdf
https://www.rural-energy.eu/solutions/8/366/Micro-combined-heat-and-power-micro-CHP#.Wrf3I2aQ0UE

further interesting links:
http://www.icrepq.com/icrepq%2712/839-kadar.pdf
https://www.theguardian.com/environment/2014/jun/13/golf-vw-car-power-plant-germany
https://www.bnl.gov/isd/documents/74453.pdf

Comment: Love this, but is it possible to go over some more specifics. For example, I’d also like to use the air conditioner from the car to provide air conditioning throughout the house, and I’d like to essentially be able to run the entire house off of one or multiple daisy chained deep cycle batteries. I am a big fan of the idea to use the radiator to heat water, and I’d probably use the already implemented heating system to heat the house. I also would be putting this all inside of a room with the exhaust piped out and the air intake also piped out, another point however would be...

Comment: ... to also use the heat from the exhaust to help provide air heating. How possible is all of this and am I trying to go too far with the idea?

Comment: A\C from car to cool house : really - have you considered the car system is designed to cool a volume of the car about 4 metres cubed and you think that will suffice for a house which can be 40 or more times larger... You should read all of the links I provided and do some thorough research as extracting the heat from the exhaust gas is possible... And it is not going too far - it helps maximise the overall efficiency of the system.

Comment: alright, and the A/C idea is simply me trying to prevent having to compensate in electrical power to run my central ac system, as that increases the draw greatly. I will read them as soon as I get the chance since my internet is somewhat slow where I am currently but when I get home I will be able to. Also, are there any alternatives to electric a/c that could be implemented into this system?

Comment: Why not think about the design of the house : in Australia one person used a suspended roof over the living space to allow free air circulation over and around the living space : it turned out that they did not need A\C at all...

Comment: I would love to do that but the house I am working with is enclosed and would require extensive work to do something like that, however with consideration to the size of the house perhaps it would be possible to simply run forced air through the air ducts with a fan powered by the generator, although this isn’t exactly what I am looking for it may be sufficient.

Comment: Using the carsd AC is not free. An interesting question might be if it would be more efficient to generate more power and use a big (heavy, no need to be portable in size or light weight) inhouse airco vs the cars airo. Not saying that one way is better, just that it might not have an obvious answer.

Answer (score 1):

Years ago I considered something similar.  The devil is in the details.  I wanted to use an automotive diesel engine, and utilize the waste heat to heat the house.

Fortunately, I did some prototyping.  The first thing I found was that unless I was making lots of power, there was not enough fuel being burned, in a fairly efficient engine, to have enough waste heat to heat the house.

Similarly, the air conditioning unit put out about 5000 BTU equivalent cooling, which was too little to chill my modest house.  I would do a room, just not a house. (Of course, if the air conditioning compressor was running there was a little more heat, go figure.)

Generating the 240/120V power was not a problem, as the 48 hp diesel could potentially power a rather large alternator.  Also frequency regulation was possible within reasonably good bounds, by adapting the cruise control to be a frequency control.

But without using inverters, or perhaps some kind of a CVT or similar transmission, the engine would run at pretty much the same RPM all the time, and that was noisy.

Modern day automobile engines, are rather efficient systems.  And the 48hp diesel engine that got 52 mpg simply didn't waste much heat at about 1200 RPM, which is what would have been a good point on the power curve to generate power for the house.

Today, I might consider using a hybrid car, with an inverter off the drive battery, if I were interested. Then the car could manage the engine start/stop and charge cycles automatically.

Comment: Interesting. How long did your engine last? Did you run it enough to get a useful figure for its lifetime? How often did you do oil changes?

Comment: I did not, in the end, decide to use the car engine for power and heat.  So I never ran it much more than to do some testing and get a few data points.  For the IDI engine I was playing with there were lots of torque/RPM/HP plots available, so fitting the engine parameters was easy.  I do know at least one business in Alaska which did use a similar setup.  The diesel engine I was intending to use has instances of non-rebuilt engines getting 400 to 800k miles on them.  Longevity did not appear to be an issue.  A hybrid  with inverter looks much easier today.

Answer (score 0):

One rule would be: **don't** (unless you only need intermittent on-demand backup power)

Car engine costs perhaps 8000 EUR if purchased separately. It provides about 100 kW or so. It's 80 EUR / kW. (When purchased along with a car, the cost of the engine itself is probably much lower, perhaps even as low as 40 EUR / kW).

Heavy-duty combustion engines such as those made by Wärtsilä (disclaimer: I own some Wärtsilä stock) cost far more: 400 EUR / kW or so, despite the fact that they are much bigger and thus benefit more from economies of scale. Usually, you'd expect economy of scale results in lower prices, but this time the prices are higher. The units by Wärtsilä and similar are also heavier per watt, being stationary or attached to huge ships.

Why this nearly one order of magnitude price difference? The reason is capacity factor and lifetime.

Car engines are designed for intermittent use. 95% of the time, a car is parked. So you get only 5% capacity factor. However, 95% of the time (or I would actually say 100% of the time), you need electricity and heat.

A car can be driven 20 years only because it is parked 95% of the time. Some people claim this is inefficient because the capacity factor is too low. They envision a shared car that is used >50% of the time and parked only <50% of the time. The truth is, the shared car wouldn't last 20 years like it would in ordinary use.

If you keep a car engine continuously running, you can't expect more than a year of lifetime. Perhaps two. With oil changes twice per month! To get the desired 20 year lifetime, you need a far more expensive and a far heavier power plant by Wärtsilä or a similar company.

Your tiny little powerplant made from a car engine wouldn't last very long. I would be looking at solar power and batteries instead. In distributed generation, in many sunny regions, they are actually the cheapest power option. If you really want to burn fossil fuels, go look at some generators that have been built for the required capacity factor.

If you need intermittent backup power, an option worth looking are the small inverter generators by Honda et al. You can get a small unit for less than 1000 EUR / USD / ${CURRENCY_SIMILAR_TO_EUR_AND_USD}. However, be warned that these are only for intermittent use. Perfect for complementing a solar system as backup power for extended non-sunny periods, though.